# Why am I missing a quote in this remap?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

```
nnoremap <leader><cr> :execute "normal! i\\\<cr>\<esc>"
```

When I run that, it says:

```
E114: Missing quote: "normal! i\\\
E15: Invalid expression: "normal! i\\\
```

What's wrong with this?  I'm trying to press `i` to go into insert mode, add a  `\` character, enter a newline, then escape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the following command:

```
nnoremap <leader><cr> :execute "normal! i\\\<cr>\<esc>"
```

Here is the command which does what you want:

```
:nnoremap <leader><cr> :execute "normal! i\\\n"<cr>
```

First, `<cr>` has special meaning to `:map` (and `:abbrev` and a couple others). Most of the rhs of a mapping is processed literally, as if you were typing those characters.  With `<cr>`, `:map` acts as if you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That leaves you submitting `:execute "normal! i\\\` ... an incomplete command and thus you get the "Missing quote" error. `\n` has no such special meaning, it's just another character and is passed to `:execute` in the string parameter.

Second, you don't need to explicitly escape just like you wouldn't if you directly entered `:execute "normal! i\\\n"`. Once you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in that case (which we're doing in the mapping with the `<cr>` at the end) the insert occurs and you are returned back to command line.

If you really want to use `<esc>` ;) here's another way to do it...and I'm sure some folks would prefer this version...

```
:nnoremap <leader><cr> :star<cr>\<cr><esc>
```

(`:star` is short for `:startinsert`)